# Python: Creating Regular Expressions with Non-Conforming Text in the Middle of String

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to captures data at the beginning and the end of a string, but not in the middle. Here's a simplified example that gets across the concept:

`Player Hero wins the game on last minute goal. Score: 2. Opponent: 1. Points: 3.
Player Doug loses the game. Score: 1. Opponent: 2. Points: 0
Player Hero loses the game. Score: 1. Opponent: 3. Points: 0.
Player Guy wins the game. Score: 3. Opponent: 1. Points: 3. 
Player Hero ties the game [2ycs]. Score: 2. Opponent: 2. Points: 1. 
Player Jim has a tough go of it [1yc]. Score: 0. Opponent: 7. Points: 0.`

What I need is a regular expression that grabs "Player Hero", but ignores the middle part of the text, and instead grabs the "Score: 2. Opponent: 1. Points: 3." data part to go along with "Player Hero" (note: I don't want the data for the other players.)

I get how to capture the beginning with:

`re.compile('Player Hero')`

And the end with:

`re.compile('Score: \d*\. Opponent: \d*\. Points: \d\.')`

Where I'm struggling is figuring out how to deal with the non-conforming text in the middle of the strings, so that I can essentially combine the two regular expressions above.

Comment: What are the rules for the name? Can it have numbers, spaces, special characters? Add that info when you add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. Is your desired end result capturing the text or the values of score, opponent and points?

Comment: @tdelaney it looks like the only name Ragnar wants is Hero

Comment: If by the "name", you mean "Player Hero", then that's always the same. The end part (score, opponent, points) should vary slightly, but predictably. Both of those aspects are straight-forward, but the middle can have all sorts of weird info in the real data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the query you are looking for is just:

```
^Player Hero .+ Score: \d*\. Opponent: \d*\. Points: \d\.$
```

`.+` will match any characters
`^` will match the beginning of the line
`$` will match the end of the line

You can try it out here:
https://regex101.com/r/Y4FMXZ/1

Note that the 3rd occurrence is not a match because `Score` doesn't have a colon but I'm assuming that was a typo. Also, there is whitespace at the end of that line. If that could happen, just remove the `$`.

If you are interested in capturing the numbers, just put them in a capturing group using parenthesis.

```
^Player Hero .+ Score: (\d*)\. Opponent:? (\d*)\. Points: (\d)\.$
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the multiline (?m) directive:

```
for item in re.findall(r"(?m)^Player Hero.*?Score:\s*(\d+)\.\s*Opponent:\s*(\d+)\.\s*Points:\s*(\d+)\.?\s*$",text):
   score,oppo,points=item
   print(f"score:{score},oppo:{oppo},points:{points}")

score:2,oppo:1,points:3
score:1,oppo:3,points:0
score:2,oppo:2,points:1
```